# Android: showing and moving current position on map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to build an app that shows the current user position using an ItemOverlay on a Google Map. The problem is that I don't' know how to move an overlay, so I try to clear overlay and recreate a new, but overlays are not deleted and I see n overlays on the map instead of one.

My code is:

```
if (!mapView.getOverlays().isEmpty())
{
    mapView.getOverlays().clear();
    mapView.invalidate();
}
else
{
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Where am i?", "I'm here!");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);
}
```

It seems like clear does not delete items.

Comment: This is weird, clear + invalidate works for me. Try mapView.remove()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code and it work for me:

```
    mapOverlays.clear();
    overlay = new GeoCoderItemizedOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bluedot), mapview);
    overlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint( (latitudine),(longitudine) ), "Luogo segnalazione", address));
   mapOverlays.add(overlay);
   mapview.invalidate();
```

Is more or less the same code I posted before..

Comment: It does not work; it creates a new overlayitem without removing the previous

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use,

myMapView.getOverlays().clear()

Comment: mapView is the name of my map instance, took with mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);